# problem downloading IBM Watson Studio Desktop Trial for Microsoft Windows 64-bit

Tags: ibm-watson

I have tried twice to download IBM Watson Studio Desktop Trial for Microsoft Windows 64-bit. It's 3.3 GB and on my slow internet connection it takes many hours. The 1st time, the download just stopped about halfway through. The 2nd time, the download was only at 1.7 GB but said it was done. When I clicked on IBMWatsonStudio_x64.exe it said the file was corrupt.

I'm a Data Scientist and am quite interested in trying IBM Watson Studio Desktop Trial for Microsoft Windows 64-bit but can't get past this 1st step. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system should be Windows 10 **Enterprise** or **Professional** otherwise, it will not execute the installed file. If os is suitable for the installation, then you need to check your internet connection, it is better to have fast internet for such big files.

Comment: Thx.  I have Windows 10 Enterprise.  As you said, I think I just need a fast internet connection to make this work.